# Pivot wider with pairs of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like this:

```
id1   id2  date1        date2         len
1      3   2021-01-01   2020-12-01     2
2      3   2021-02-02   2020-12-31     1
3      5   2021-03-01   2020-09-30     3
4      5   2021-03-03   2021-01-30     4
...
```

For each `id2` there is exactly 2 rows. If we let `A` represent the first of these 2 rows and `B` the second, I would like to obtain this:

```
id2   A.date1     A.date2     B.date1      B.date2     A.len     B.len
3     2021-01-01  2020-12-01  2021-02-02   2020-12-31    2         1
5     2021-03-01  2020-09-30  2021-03-03   2021-01-30    3         4
```

I thought there might be a way to do this with `pivot_wider` but I haven't been able to do it.

Here is the toy data:

```
data.frame(id1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), id2 = c(3, 3, 5, 5), date1 = as.Date(c("2021-01-01", "2021-02-02", "2021-03-01", "2021-03-03")), 
         date2 = as.Date(c("2020-12-01", "2020-12-31", "2020-09-30", "2021-01-30")), len = c(2,1,3,4))
```

Answer (score 4):

We can create a sequence column grouped by 'id2' (`rowid` from data.table does that in a single step).  Use that column as the `names_from` and specify the multiple columns in `values_from`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidur)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   # // or do a group by 
   # group_by(id2) %>%
   # mutate(rn = LETTERS[row_number()]) %>%
   mutate(rn = LETTERS[rowid(id2)]) %>% 
   select(-id1) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(date1, date2, len))
```

Answer (score 1):

a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
DT[, AB := LETTERS[ rowid( id2 ) ] ][]
dcast( DT, id2 ~ AB, value.var = c("date1", "date2", "len") )

#    id2    date1_A    date1_B    date2_A    date2_B len_A len_B
# 1:   3 2021-01-01 2021-02-02 2020-12-01 2020-12-31     2     1
# 2:   5 2021-03-01 2021-03-03 2020-09-30 2021-01-30     3     4
```

**sample data**

```
DT <- data.table::fread("id1   id2  date1        date2         len
1      3   2021-01-01   2020-12-01     2
2      3   2021-02-02   2020-12-31     1
3      5   2021-03-01   2020-09-30     3
4      5   2021-03-03   2021-01-30     4")
```